# ActiveX control: create gridview with FormView

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to develop a Video-Surveillance-Systems,something like you can control dozens of monitors just in one view!Unfortunately i'm fresh in C++，so i need help.
Here,i want to create gridview with FormView like 3 * 3 or 4 * 4...
Could anyone donate demos for me or just the key-code
Thanks advance！

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to create a separate window for each cell in your grid and then either lay them out manually in your view or have a look at CSplitterWnd.